# Port forwarding with PROLiNK H5004N ADSL

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port

I am trying to setup a virtual host. So far it's working on LAN but when I try to access it on another network, it's pointing me to my router's interface. I have PROLiNK H5004N ADSL2+ Wireless Modem/Router. I am not that familiar with port forwarding so I think this is the problem. Anyways, here's my configuration(Router Features>Virtual Server Forwarding):

```
ServerName:   WEB
Protocol: TCP
Local IP Address: 192.168.1.104
Local Port:   80-80
WAN IP Address:   my.ip.add.ress
WAN Port: 80-80
```

Here's my virtualhost config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\web"
    ServerName www.testweb.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
my.ip.add.ress  www.testweb.com
```

Answer (score 1):

first always test with after any minor change with telnet command:

```
telnet yourpublicIP 80
```

if you get message connection timout you need to ckeck port forwarding.

on port forwarding  configure always this way:

```
PROTOCOL:TCP
LOCAL IP:192.168.1.104
LOCAL PORT:80
REMOTE IP: any if options or leave blank.
REMOTE PORT:80
```

this is the basic parameters to enable port forwarding, just stay with the basics  till work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I reconfigured my port forwarding to yours. I also added this line to my hosts file "**my.ip.add.ress www.testweb.com**". I tried accessing **www.testweb.com** through my browser and still no luck. It still points me to my router's interface instead of web server from **192.168.1.104**. I'm going to check and test everything later. Thank you!